# Angular2+ callling a function in the view/template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

When I call a function in the view of an Angular component the function gets called over and over again. For example:

**nightclub.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nightclub',
  templateUrl: './nightclub.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nightclub.component.css']
})
export class NightclubComponent {
  doStuff(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

**nightclub.component.html**

```
{{doStuff()}}
```

This will call the doStuff() method over and over again.

### Question:

Should one ever do this? If so, in what situation can this be beneficial?

Comment: What do you mean by "This will call the doStuff() method over and over again" ?

Comment: Try logging something before returning one in my function in an Angular app. If you then check console you will see that it is spammed by the function being called many times

Comment: Yes, this is a normal behaviour of Angular2+ Change detection strategy. The framework should check the template and the model then update the view if there will be any changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be called every change detection cycle it is not advised to use a function inside the template as it will not be large performance hit.

The implementation of the function / data you want to show on the template is highly dependent of your use case.

Example:

If are parsing text then a pipe would be a great option as it can be memoized

If you changes to the data can happen outside of the component where `Inputs` and `Outputs` cannot be used then an Observable would be a good option.

Comment: So Angular checks for changes multiple times a second?

Comment: It happens once per applicationRef tick in production and twice in dev mode
If you want to optimize one way is using `OnPush`

you can read more https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers&comments I would add some suggestions in order to optimize your code.
First of all, take a look at this well-explained [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybNj-id0kjY) (~40 minutes) from the last ng-conf ("Optimizing an Angular application - Minko Gechev").

The main idea is to use OnPush change detection strategy in your components, use Pure Pipes for methods like in your example and the memoization of functions.

But if you have OnPush Strategy in your Component and changes came from the "outside Angular's world" - you also can Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` to your component and manually call `markForCheck()` (for more details take a look [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef))